# MySQL - Return matching text from a search over multiple columns

Tags: mysql

Assume I have a table which looks like this:

```
Ref|Start point|End point
-------------------------
  1|Narva      |Tallinn
  2|Tartu      |Viljandi
  3|Pärnu      |Tartu
  4|Tartu      |Jõgeva
```

Two columns here contain place names. Now I would like to search for a place name matching some pattern in both columns and return the matching place names, which means:

- Search for 'Ta%' => return Tallinn, Tartu
- Search for '%va' => return Narva, Jõgeva

Is there any way to achieve this with some suitable MySQL query? The structure of the table is fixed, because I need to run this search on an already existing database. But I may create temporary tables, if this would help.

Edit: To clarify, I would like to get a list of matching place names, *not* a list of matching rows. So a query of this type does not yield the desired result:

```
SELECT * FROM routes WHERE start_point LIKE '%va' OR end_point LIKE '%va'
```

This query would return something like:

- 1, Narva, Tallinn
- 4, Tartu, Jõgeva

But I would rather like:

- Narva
- Jõgeva

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can run 2 queries for it

**1)**

```
SELECT start_point FROM routes WHERE start_point LIKE '%va'
```

**2)**

```
SELECT end_point FROM routes WHERE end_point LIKE '%va'
```

first one will give the output from `startpoint` and second one will give the output from `endpoint`

**UPDATE :**

to RUN combine both of them you can use `UNION` like this

```
SELECT start_point FROM routes WHERE start_point LIKE '%va'
UNION
SELECT end_point FROM routes WHERE end_point LIKE '%va'
```

Comment: Indeed, that's one possibility. I'm wondering whether one can put the results from both queries together so that each match appears only once, but I guess with UNION this should be possible somehow.

Comment: Just tried with UNION and this gives me just what I was looking for - even a lot simpler than I thought. Thanks!

Comment: yes you can use `UNION` between both of above query to run at once.

Answer (score 0):

```
1. select Ref,Start_Point,End_point from table where Start_point like 'Ta%' or End_point like 'Ta%'
2. select Ref,Start_Point,End_point from table where Start_point like '%va' or End_point like '%va'
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not quite what I am looking for, please see the clarification I added to my original question.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT distinct t1.startpoint, t2.endpoint
FROM `yourtablename` AS t1, ( 
    SELECT *
    FROM `yourtablename`
    WHERE endpoint LIKE 'Ta%'
) AS t2
WHERE t1.startpoint LIKE 'Ta%'
and t1.startpoint <> t2.endpoint
group by t1.startpoint, t2.endpoint
```

Comment: Great, this seems to work almost as desired. Now I get multiple copies of each result. Is there a way to get each match only once (using DISTINCT or something similar)?

Comment: This looks better! But unfortunately it only works when both columns contain a match... So for example, when I search for 'Nar%', I get an empty result, because there is no match in the end_point column.